# Extracting a Outer Join from Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, outer-join

I have the following two models in my Project.

```
class Blog(models.Model):   
    title=models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, default='')
    content=models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=False, default='')

class UserLikedBlogs(models.Model):
    blog=models.ForeignKey(TTSServiceModel.TTSService, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

All Users who login are able to see blogs of other users. The current logged in user can "like" a certain blog, which adds an entry in the UserLikedBlogs table.

I wish to now display all the blogs present in the system to a logged in User, but I also wish to show blogs that the User has liked.

I understand that this should get all entries from the Blog table, with additional columns from the UserLikedBlogs table, where the data is present only for blogs liked by the user, not otherwise.

This is a classic case of a Outer Join where, common elements between two sets are associated with all elements from one of the tables participating in the join.

I have been reading documentation from django and on SO, but i cant seem to find the right syntax to do this.

My current hacky way of doing this is to user `Pandas` and join the two data sets in Python, rather than a query. I am certain there is a better way, but just cant find it. Can you help?

Comment: You say you want to display "all blogs" but also "liked blogs" - but "liked blogs" is a *subset* of all blogs, so what's the problem with querying simply all blogs? Do you want to display them in some different order, e.g. Liked blogs first and then the rest? Or also display some information that a blog is "liked"?

Comment: The user comes to a view. The view is loaded. All blogs are visible, in green color font. Some of the blogs are liked by the user, and those have to show up as blue color font.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can try like this:

```
Blog.objects.filter(userlikedblogs__user=request.user)
```

Here I am using [**`reverse relation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/relations/) between `UserLikedBlogs` and `Blog` to get the Blogs liked by user.

---

Update based on comment added by OP at the bottom of this answer:

Here basically you want to annotate the information if user liked the blog or not. You can do that like using [**`conditional expressions`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/):

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, BooleanField

blogs = Blog.objects.annotate(
     liked=Case(
         When(userlikedblogs__user=request.user, then=Value(True)),
         default=Value(False),
         output_field=BooleanField(),
     )
)
```

And use that blogs in `template`(when you send them via context from view to template):

```
{% for blog in blogs %}
    {% if blog.liked %}
        <a style="background:blue" href="{% url 'blog:detail' blog.pk %}">{{ blog.title }}</a>
    {% else %}
        <a style="background:green" href="{% url 'blog:detail' blog.pk %}">{{ blog.title }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The user comes to a view. The view is loaded. All blogs are visible, in green color font. Some of the blogs are liked by the user, and those have to show up as blue color font.

Comment: Where does it reference the blog primary key in user liked blogs? Does it implicitly do it on the FK?

Comment: For the first yep, second part I don't understand what you mean. Please see the documentation link on related objects.

Comment: What if instead of only one field, we wished to have all fields from the UserLikedBlogs in the same row as the Blogs queryset?

Comment: You can't, because the relation is ForeignKey, not OneToOne. But you can use another for-loop the fetch those fields, and there will be no DB hits if you use `prefetch_related`.

Answer (score 1):

> All blogs are visible, in green color font. Some of the blogs are liked by the user, and those have to show up as blue color font.

This means you want to query all Blogs, but have a way of telling that specific one is favorited for current user. You can achieve that by using `annotate` when constructing a queryset for your template

```py
Blog.objects.annotate(is_favorite=Exists(UserLikedBlogs.objects.filter(blog=OuterRef('pk'), user=request.user)))
```

then in your template you can simply check `blog.is_favorite` to see if it is favorited for current user

Comment: I think this will make a query for every blog entry in the Blogs table, and see if it is in the User Liked Blogs Table. Let me look at the Cost of this query and let you know

Comment: @Rupin it should make a subquery within the same query, which at least postgre can optimize pretty nicely. I.e. it won't make additional queries for every blog instance

Comment: What if instead of only one field, we wished to have all fields from the UserLikedBlogs in the same row as the Blogs queryset?

Comment: I really like this more than a `Case/When/default/output_field` monster :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following

```
allLikedBlogs=Blogs.objects.all().values('title', 'content', 'userlikedblogs__user')
```

This led to the ORM making a Left Outer Join.

Comment: Won't this return the same `Blog` twice if more than one `User` liked it?